# Cannot figure out the POST into Json data ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, http-post

This is my app.js

```
volkswagenApp
            .controller('VolkswagenCtrl',
                 ['$http' , function($http){
                     var vw =  this;
                     vw.gegevens = [];
                     $http.get('autos.json').success(function(data){
                     vw.gegevens = data;
                     });
                }]);

volkswagenApp
    .controller('FormController',function(){
            this.gegevens={};
            /*this.addGegevens = function(gegeven) {
            gegeven.gegevens.push(this.gegeven);
            this.gegevens={};
            }*/

            this.addGegevens = function(gegeven){
                this.gegevens.datum = Date.now();
                vw.gegevens.push(this.gegeven);
                this.gegeven = {};
               }
    });
```

and this is my index.html:

```
<span ng-show="show">
  <form name="inputForm" class="form-group" ng-controller="FormController as autoctrl" 
  ng-submit="inputForm.$valid && autoctrl.addGegevens(gegeven)" novalidate>
    <br>

        <p> Type: <input type="text" name="autoctrl.type" ng-model="type" style="margin-left:52px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="2" maxlength="10" required /></p>
        <p>Bouwjaar: <input type="number" name="bouwjaar" ng-model="autoctrl.bouwjaar"  style="margin-left:22px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="4" maxlength="4" required /></p>
         <p>Km: <input type="number" name="km" ng-model="autoctrl.km" style="margin-left:60px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="2" maxlength="6" required /></p>
        <p>Brandstof:  <input id="select" name="brandstof" ng-model="autoctrl.brandstof" style="margin-left:20px; padding-left:5px;" minlength="3" maxlength="7" required/></p>

        <p>Kenteken: <input type="text" name="kenteken" ng-model="autoctrl.kenteken" style="margin-left:22px; padding-left:5px; width:165px;" minlength="6" maxlength="9" required /></p>
        <p>Datum:         <input type="text" name="datum" ng-model="autoctrl.datum"  style="margin-left:40px; padding-left:5px;  width:165px;" minlength="3" maxlength="11" required  /></p>
        <p>checked: <input type="checkbox"  name="checked" ng-model="autoctrl.checked" style="margin-left:28px;" required /></p>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Toevoegen</button>

        <div>{{inputForm.$valid}}</div>
        {{ PostDataResponse }} 
        {{autoctrl.gegeven.type}}
        {{autoctrl.gegeven.bouwjaar}}
</form>
</span>
```

and this is the error in the console:

```
   Error: Can't find variable: vw
```

I tried everything, searched the docs. watched several tutorials and i cant find out where im going wrong. This is for a school project. Please help!

Comment: In `FormController` `vw` is not defined.

Comment: @Dann : you can not intialize variable like : var vw =  this; , VW will be undefined

Comment: where you have used ng-controller in which tag?

Comment: @Dann: And then after if you still not getting data from $http, then check for content type, you will need to set it.

Comment: @Dann : Nothing linked to the question but a small advice. You should write your code in English. If someone needs to help you or to work alone on the project it would be better to be in English thus anyone can take your code

Comment: @JigarPrajapati its the formController what isn't workinn, the volksWagenCtrl works fine.

Comment: @Aravind in the <form> tag

Comment: @Weedoze thanx for the advice, i trie to do it as much as i can but for my own over view i also typed the ng-model in dutch, will think about it next time!

Comment: @ram1993 i understand that vw is not defined in FormController but how can i adjust this

Comment: As far as I believe you want to use `vw` from `VolkswagenCtrl` to `FormController`. See different ways of sharing data between two controller in angularjs. Best way I would recommend is Service/Factory.

Answer (score 0):

vw is declared in `VolkswagenCtrl` scope, not in `FormController` scope. You can use `$resource` module to fetch ajax data and inject some service into `FormController`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: isn't there a way that i can just adjust the FormController?